# How to group related form elements in a PHP page?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a PHP page whose purpose is taking user information for job recruitment. This page contains a form which has many input fields. This form is as good as a resume of the candidate.

There is a section in the form where user enters his skill set the format of that section as follows

- skill set dropdown
- skill name dropdown
- proficiency dropdown
- exp. years dropdown
- exp. month dropdown

There are same kind of 8 rows as above. User must fill at least one row in above section. So my question is while submitting the form on above page, is there any way to group that values of the same type in one section to send to action page.

Comment: 1. there are no pages in php. 2. there are no form in php. show us code you already done.

Comment: give same selects a name like `group1[]` (regard the square brackets), so PHP  converts it to an array

Comment: @rabudde Thank You friend but can you explain it a bit more of please give me a link where this will be explained in detail. Thanks You

Comment: @Param-Ganak The downvotes are mostly for not reading [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use an array. If you have a name attribute for each `<select>` in a row.
like `<select name="proficiency">` you can change it to `<select name="proficiency[]">` to make it an array. Then you can reuse the same name in the array for more `select` tags to add them onto the same array.

You could also do all 8 rows of `<select>`s as a 2D array like:

`<select name="skills[name][]">`

`<select name="skills[proficiency][]">`

etc.

Comment: Thank you! for your guidance. It will help me allot. But my friend there are many section in my form which has same type and number of controls in them like textbox selct dropdown box text area etc. so is this solution is applicable to all these kind of controls? Also please tell me what this technique is called? and where I will get more information on it? Thank You!

Comment: @Param-Ganak Yes you can use this solution on any type of `input`. It is how HTML forms create arrays. There is a small bit of information on it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use an array for your form field names and pass that array along via `POST`

HTML

```
<input name="skills[]" ...
```

PHP

```
foreach($_POST['skills'] as $skill)
{
 ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. <input name="skill[]" ... In this code the "skills[]" is a php code or we can declare it as written by you. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but can you not just group the $_POST variables into an array by analyzing the results then comparing and matching the grouped values?

Comment: @ willium Thank you friend form replying. As per your suggestion I can do that by my question is to group such variables in in an array and send this array to next action page. so on action page we can access the all values using one variable which is good for coding and for maintenance. Thank You!

Comment: you can do with within the php form and just set the method to POST and action to your next page. Otherwise you can use CURL to submit it as POST request. Keep in mine, PHP does not have pages on forms, I think you should share more code and try elaborating.